# How to stop event-handler?

Tags: c#, multithreading, camera, event-handling

To show the live-stream of a camera an event-handler is started. The code for this event is:

```
       private void onFrameEventFocusCam(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;

        Int32 s32MemID;
        Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);


        // Read Camera bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemID, out bitmap);


        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            // Convert bitmap to WPF-Image
            var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);
            var hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

            System.Windows.Media.ImageSource wpfBitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            image_fokus.Source = wpfBitmap;
            image_fokus.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill;
            image_fokus.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;

            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            bitmap.Dispose();

        }));
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Now, when I close the camera (see code below), it gives me an error-message "Thread was interrupted from a waiting state." back and the debugger jumps to the Dispatcher.Invoke-Code (see above).

When I uncomment the MessageBox.Show("0"), the error is **NOT** shown anymore and everything works fine after pressing the OK-Button of this messagebox.

This is the code for closing the camera and the event-handler:

```
             // Close Camera
                Camera.Acquisition.Stop(uEye.Defines.DeviceParameter.Force);                 
                Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEventFocusCam;              // remove Event

             // MessageBox.Show("0");

                uEye.Defines.Status statusRet = 0;
                statusRet = Camera.Exit();
```

Does someone knows what I am doing wrong and how to avoid such error-message (without the messagebox)?

Thanks!

---

### UPDATED Code

These steps are performed:

1) Camera is opened and the **onFrameEventFocusCam** event-handler is called

2) The image is valid and shown on the GUI

3) In the Main UI the camera is closed again and the event disabled

4) For some reasons (race-condition?) the same event is re-activated again

This is the part of the main-thread where the camera is closed again:

```
    else
    {
      // Close Camera     
      uEye.Defines.Status statusRet = 0;
      statusRet = Camera.Acquisition.Stop(uEye.Defines.DeviceParameter.DontWait);

      Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEventFocusCam;              // remove Event
      statusRet = Camera.Exit();

    } // end of else..
```

After the "}" the following event is reactivated again and it jumps again to the onFrameEventFocusCam!

```
    private void onFrameEventFocusCam(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;

        Int32 s32MemID;
        Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);


        // Read Camera bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemID, out bitmap);


        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            // Convert bitmap to WPF-Image
            var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);
            var hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

            System.Windows.Media.ImageSource wpfBitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            image_fokus.Source = wpfBitmap;
            image_fokus.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill;
            image_fokus.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;

            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            bitmap.Dispose();

        }));
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that while your program is executing the "close camera" code, the camera has raised an event, causing the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method to be called, thus causing the event-raising thread to wait until the UI thread can process the invoked method.

Presumably you are executing the "close camera" code in the UI thread (e.g. in response to a user input, like a button click or something). This means that event-raising thread cannot proceed until you're done with the "close camera" code. But the last thing that code does is call `Camera.Exit()`. This apparently causes the camera library to interrupt the event-raising thread which was waiting, causing the exception.

The exception goes away when you call `MessageBox.Show()`, because that causes the `Dispatcher` to pump window messages, including the one that processes the invoked method for your call to `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. This unblocks the event handler, letting it return before you get to the point of calling `Camera.Exit()`, avoiding the need for the camera library to interrupt the thread.

I think the simplest way to fix it in this case is simply to call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` (or the newer `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()`) method. That will cause the method invocation to be queued asynchronously, allowing the event handler to return immediately without waiting on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the very good answer, now I better understand what is the root cause!! 
Could you please give me an example how the code for the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(..?..)` looks like?

Comment: It's exactly like the call to `Dispatcher.Invoke()` you have now. You can literally just change the method name from `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke` to effect the change. No other changes to your code should be needed.

Comment: After changing `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke` the thread disappears from the process overview and the camera is closed (Camera.Exit)- so far so good. When I proceed in the code, the same event appears again although I do no call it inside the code! How is it possible that this thread is re-activated although the thread was closed?

Comment: and/or do I need to set a specific Dispatcher Priority?

Comment: The overload of `Invoke()` you're using doesn't set the priority; I don't think you should need to use a different overload of `BeginInvoke()` (i.e. one that does include a priority parameter). But if you do, `DispatcherPriority.Normal` should be fine. As for the event "reappearing", impossible for me to answer without a complete code example. But it's certainly theoretically possible that your UI thread and the camera library thread are in a race and that it already retrieved the event handler value before you unsubscribed, in preparation for raising the event again.

Comment: I updated the code (see above). Let's assume there is a race condition, is it possible to put in a wait in order that the event has enough time to finish its task? How would it looks like?

Comment: "it jumps again to the onFrameEventFocusCam!" -- to the very beginning of the method (i.e. the event itself is raised again) or to the code block in your anonymous method (i.e. the `Action` invoked by `Dispatcher`)? Either way, you can address the race by setting a flag (declared e.g. `private volatile bool disableEvent;`) before you unsubscribe the event, and in the event handler code, simply ignore the event and/or `Dispatcher`-invocation if the flag is set. But do you really need to? Assuming the code _works_ and the event is raised/invoked only the one additional time, isn't that fine?

Comment: it jumps to the code block with the **Action invoked by Dispatcher**. I tried to use such boolean flag where I ignore the Dispatcher invocation but if I do so the application does not  work in the way it should and fails. Generally it would not matter if the event is raised one additional time but it throws allways the error: **Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.** at the code: **var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);**.

Comment: @Norick: If the flag doesn't work, you implemented it wrong. That said, you may find it is just as easy and effective to immediately copy the `Bitmap` object the camera library gives you instead of waiting for the invoked delegate. I.e. move the first statement of the anonymous method, `var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);` to just after `Camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemID, out bitmap);` statement, i.e. in the event handler itself, just before you call `BeginInvoke()`. That way, the invoked delegate isn't trying to use a `Bitmap` object project directly by the camera library, so it will stay valid.

Comment: yeah this worked for me, when I moved the bitmap statement outside the **BeginInvoke()**! Thanks for your support!!!